# Indexing Pandas DataFrame containing lists of strings after loading pickled DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, dtype

I'm trying to get the row indices of a pandas DataFrame, where the entries are being queried for containing a string amongst a list.

However, after pickling a DataFrame and then loading, the column data seems to handle differently than when working prior to pickling.

e.g. for the following DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

DB = pd.DataFrame(columns=['message', 'authors', 'style'])
DB['message'] = ['hello', 'i wrote', 'this passage']

DB.loc[1]['authors'] = ['Adam', 'Bob']
DB.loc[2]['authors'] = ['Bob', 'Charlie']

print(DB)
```

...output...

```
        message         authors style
0         hello             NaN   NaN
1       i wrote     [Adam, Bob]   NaN
2  this passage  [Bob, Charlie]   NaN
```

Retrieving all the column indices where the `'author'` column contains the word `'Bob'` can be done using the [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) method:

```
DB.authors.astype(str).str.contains('Adam')
```

Out:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: authors, dtype: bool
```

Leaving the DataFrame column in its original format (I think...) which can be seen by querying the following:

```
print(DB2.authors[1])
```

Out:

```
['Adam', 'Bob']
```

However, if you first pickle the DataFrame for reloading somewhere else and then perform the same operation, you can see that the format of the DataFrame column has been changed in place:

```
DB.to_pickle('dummy_database.pkl')
DB2 = pd.read_pickle('dummy_database.pkl')
print(DB2.authors.astype(str).str.contains('Adam'))
print(DB2.authors[1])
```

Out:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: authors, dtype: bool


"['Adam', 'Bob']"
```

...as shown by the quotations around what was originally a list of strings.

Is there anyway to undo this apparent in place change of datatype, and could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong which is causing this behaviour?

---

Useful note: prior to the query operation `DB2.authors.astype(str).str.contains('Adam')` you can still call `DB2.authors[1]` as before, and you appear to have the same format: `Out: ['Adam', 'Bob']`.

Comment: Can you provide your python/pandas versions? I get a list as output of `type(DB2.authors[1])` after pickling (python 3.8, pandas 1.5.2).

Comment: Sure! Python 3.8.10 and pandas==1.5.2

Comment: I tried with Pyhon 3.8.10 and 3.916 and Pandas 1.5.2. Your code works well.

Comment: Oh... that's really strange, I have no idea what I'm doing differently then in that case :')